# ie breaks head element on conditional comment

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I've got something strange.
We've got multiple servers, some of which we use internal, some of which we use external. Now we use one of those internal servers as a testserver for a website.
This is a Joomla website.

Now there is a conditional comment on the template:
`<!--[if IE 7]-->  <link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/ie7only.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <!--[endif]-->`

When opening the joomla website on the internal server in Internet Explorer we get the comment as text on the webpage:
`<!--[if IE 7]--> <!--[endif]-->`
And the header is broken. This and everything after this is shown in the body tag.

When placing this template on the external server, on which the website is available for the rest of the world, we don't get this message in Internet Explorer.

Is there anyone who knows why this could happen? I can't find anything on the web about this.

*Extra needed information will be editted when asked*

Comment: what versions of IE do you use for the external and internal hosted page?

Comment: The same. Both pages are looked at in IE 11.0.26